# Father, two sons, 999 paintings

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

This is a question for a job application:
"A father has two sons and 999 paintings. Each painting has a different value: first is worth 1, second is worth 2 and so on, until the final painting is worth 999. He would like to divide all of his paintings to his two sons, so that each son gets equal value. How many ways are there to do that with 999 paintings?
Example: if father had 7 paintings, he could divide them fairly by giving the first son paintings 1,6 and 7. Second son would get 2,3,4 and 5. Both would have equal value in sum, 14. In case when there are 7 paintings, father can fairly divide them in 4 ways (other 3 not listed here), so the solution is 4.
HINT: the number might be large, so send us the last 10 digits and sketch of your solution."

What I did was try to use a brute force approach, adding up all the possible combinations by writing a c# program which writes it's own c# program with loops within loops, like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (short i = 2; i <= 999; i++) //starts from 2 because 1 is always added to the total for one side
{
    sb.AppendLine("for (byte i" + i.ToString() + " = 0; i" + i.ToString() + " < 2; i" + i.ToString() + "++)");
    sb.AppendLine("{");
}

for (int i = 2; i <= 999; i++)
{
    sb.Append("if (i" + i.ToString() + " == 1) { total += " + i.ToString() + "; }\n");
}

for (short i = 2; i <= 999; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine("}");
}
```

And then adding this after the if blocks in the result:

```
if (total == 249750)
{
    count++; //count is a BigInteger
}
total = 1;
```

This approach should technically work (as tested on a smaller number of paintings), but the problem is it is a HUUUGE number and it would take like a million years or so to calculate the result on my computer this way... Is there some mathematical trick to do this in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Hell no, this is way out of my league :D
For the moment, at least...

Comment: Yes I understand that, I am not asking so I can cheat the interview, I'm asking so I can learn something new and hopefully add something new to my skillset.
And I posted the link so in case someone who can solve it can apply if he wants to and meets the requirements. (it got edited out by mod, apparently that's against the rules)

Comment: Think before you code. Calculate some smaller cases of the problem by hand. Is there a pattern? Let f(n) be the number of equitable divisions of n paintings. Can you write a recurrence relation for f(n)? If not, does defining a partial solution function help? Hint: let g(n, t) be the number of divisions of n paintings where the eldest son receives total value t.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easier to approach the more general problem of determining how many ways the first son can get value `k`, where `k` is a parameter. There's an art to figuring out the appropriate generalization; it's taught in algorithms courses under the name *dynamic programming*.

Let `x` be a variable. The mathematical insight needed is that, for `n` paintings, the coefficient of `x^k` in the product of polynomials

```
x (1 + x^2) (1 + x^3) ... (1 + x^n)
```

in `x` is the number of ways that the first son can get value `k` (including the painting of value `1`). This is because this product distributes to

```
(sum for i_2 = 0 to 1) (sum for i_3 = 0 to 1) ... (sum for i_n = 0 to 1)
    x^(1 + 2 i_2 + 3 i_3 + ... + n i_n),
```

which effectively is how your brute force solution evaluates this product. The dynamic program here is equivalent to distributing the factors one by one instead of all at once, e.g.,

```
x (1 + x^2) = x + x^3
x (1 + x^2) (1 + x^3) = (x + x^3) (1 + x^3)
                      = x + x^3 + x^4 + x^6.
x (1 + x^2) (1 + x^3) (1 + x^4) = (x + x^3 + x^4 + x^6) (1 + x^3)
                                = x + x^3 + x^4 + x^6 + x^4 + x^6 + x^7 + x^9
                                = x + x^3 + 2 x^4 + 2 x^6 + x^7 + x^9.
```

The time savings comes from duplicate terms. Already we have only six terms to contend with instead of eight (two to the third power).

Keeping only the last ten digits means that we can evaluate this product in the ring of integers modulo `10^10`. As a result, we can reduce the intermediate coefficients modulo that number to avoid resorting to bignums. This trick, well known to the competitive programming community, is covered formally in courses on abstract algebra or number theory.

In [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Coefficient[x%20Product[1%2Bx%5Ei%2C%7Bi%2C2%2C7%7D]%2Cx%5E%28Sum[i%2C%7Bi%2C1%2C7%7D]%2F2%29]):

```
In[1]:= Coefficient[x Product[1+x^i,{i,2,7}],x^(Sum[i,{i,1,7}]/2)]

Out[1]= 4

In[2]:= Coefficient[x Product[1+x^i,{i,2,8}],x^(Sum[i,{i,1,8}]/2)]

Out[2]= 7
```

In Java:

```
public class PartitionPaintings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] p = new long[] {0, 1};
        for (int i = 2; i <= Integer.parseInt(args[0]); i++) {
            long[] q = new long[p.length + i];
            for (int k = 0; k <= p.length - 1; k++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                    q[k + i * j] = (q[k + i * j] + p[k]) % 10000000000L;
                }
            }
            p = q;
        }
        System.out.println(p[(p.length - 1) / 2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "This trick, well known to the competitive programming community..." 
I knew there was a trick involved :D Now since I don't understand most of what you said, do you know of a good free online course on abstract algebra or numbers theory?

Comment: @infamous Nothing that I personally can recommend. Just learning about modular arithmetic will be enough to cope with last n digits (modulo m) output requirements. Note that the real speedup is from switching polynomial multiplication algorithms.

Comment: The answer almost makes sense.. **except** for the application of modular arithmetic part, which is to keep the numbers low without need for BigInteger... It turns out, that 10^10 is a good number to use for mod, is based on assumption that the answer is less than 10 digit long... However, that is not the case... Replacing long with BigInteger in this code gives **completely** different answer.. 100s of digit long.... If I am still mistaken, someone please clarify.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Also, I am no math major.. and might sound dumb, but I am sure curious, how do you get the insight about the polynomial being related to the answer (with its coefficients and stuff) (hope answer is not a PhD in Maths)?

Comment: @VikasGupta [Generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) can be used for a lot of cool things. The business with the modulo is because it is necessary only to find the last ten digits of the number of feasible partitions.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Ah.. thanks for the link, and clarifying the 10 digit part.. Read the question again.. it does say last 10 digits :) Good stuff.. :D

Comment: I get what the modulo is for but I don't get the other parts, like how do you get that Mathematica formula, and of course I don't cause I don't even understand what coefficient means in this context, what the different brackets are for etc. And when I start to read something like the wipipedia article an generating functions I see that that there are like 20 other things I need to learn about before I can understand that etc. MIT's OpenCourseWare on youtube covers dynamic programming in part 19 and 20, so maybe I'll try that when I have some extra free time...

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Can you please clarify why isn't the first term `1+x` instead of just `x`.

Comment: @VikasGupta That's how I had it originally, but it didn't match the (presumably working) code in the question. The difference is whether we view the sons as being distinguishable or not (if not, then we distinguish them by whether they got the value-1 painting).

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for mathematics.

You are basically looking for a [number partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), one with [distinct parts](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath556/kmath556.htm).

The total value of all paintings is the sum of integers 1…999. `(n * (n+1)) / 2` [according to Gauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), so we get: `(999 * 1000) / 2 = 499500`. So each son is supposed to get paintings with a total value of 249750.

Now, we just need to find the number partitions of that value with distinct parts that do not exceed 999. We assign each partition we find as the set of paintings for one son, and the second son will get the remaining paintings (which have the same total value).

So the only tricky part is figuring out the partition function for distinct and bounded parts. But I guess you could also do this programmatically.

Mohammadreza Bidar, from the Sharif University of Technology in Tehran, actually wrote a paper with the promising title *“Partition of an Integer into Distinct Bounded Parts, Identities and Bounds”*. You can read it in [*INTEGERS*, volume 12](http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/vol12.html) (it’s the 8th article there).

Comment: 499500 is the total value, so each son is supposed get half of that (249750), and that is the easy part. Didn't know about that Gauss formula, but I already did that with a for loop and I skipped that part in the question, sorry, should have been clearer about that...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write that number, no idea why I didn’t.

Comment: how this is a solution of the problem ?